# SQL how to count numbers from a field

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

```
Customer Id.  Line#      Code
  234           1         40
  234           2         25,40
  234           3         12,40,52
  234           4         14
  327           1         34
  327           2         40,56
```

Need to get the count of the number 40 in each customer Id

So result should be

```
     Customer id.      Count
       234               3
       327               1
```

Can you please suggest on how to write the query for this

Answer (score 2):

You can get this using `like`:

```
select customerid,
       sum(case when ',' + code + ',' like '%,40,%' then 1 else 0 end)
from table t
group by customerid;
```

Your ned to do this suggests a flaw in your data structure.  You are storing lists of numbers in a string -- that is a bad idea.  After all, you shouldn't store numbers as characters.

Instead, you should have a junction/association table with one row per `customerid` and `code`.  This would make a query like this easier to write and more efficient.

Comment: this solution will not work when 40 is the only number or 40 is at first or at last position.

Comment: @NithinGangadharan . . . Of course it will.  That is why the commas are inserted in both the pattern and the string to match.  It also fixes the problem of `40` matching `4` or `0` -- which this does not.

Comment: @NithinGangadharan Why not? It works correctly for me when only 40 is in the list and when it begins and ends the list. Also, the asserted flaw is probably appropriate.

Comment: Thanks Nithin , my result looked like this ,                Customer Id.  Line#      Count
  234           1        1
  234           2        1
  234           3        1
  234           4        0
  327           1        0
  327           2        1                                      if I comment the 'line'.  Then the result looks like this.    
Customer Id.       Count
  234                1
  234                0                                           I am not getting the count as 3

Comment: Thank you everybody it works , just had to use the statement along with the having clause.       Having(sum(case when ',' + code + ',' like '%,40,%' then 1 else 0 end))>'1'

Answer (score 0):

You will first have to create a Split function.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.Split(@String nvarchar(4000), @Delimiter char(1))
RETURNS @Results TABLE (Items nvarchar(4000))
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @INDEX INT
DECLARE @SLICE nvarchar(4000)
-- HAVE TO SET TO 1 SO IT DOESNT EQUAL Z
--     ERO FIRST TIME IN LOOP
SELECT @INDEX = 1
WHILE @INDEX !=0
BEGIN
-- GET THE INDEX OF THE FIRST OCCURENCE OF THE SPLIT CHARACTER
SELECT @INDEX = CHARINDEX(@Delimiter,@STRING)
-- NOW PUSH EVERYTHING TO THE LEFT OF IT INTO THE SLICE VARIABLE
IF @INDEX !=0
SELECT @SLICE = LEFT(@STRING,@INDEX - 1)
ELSE
SELECT @SLICE = @STRING
-- PUT THE ITEM INTO THE RESULTS SET
INSERT INTO @Results(Items) VALUES(@SLICE)
-- CHOP THE ITEM REMOVED OFF THE MAIN STRING
SELECT @STRING = RIGHT(@STRING,LEN(@STRING) - @INDEX)
-- BREAK OUT IF WE ARE DONE
IF LEN(@STRING) = 0 BREAK
END
RETURN
END
```

Now use the below query:

```
SELECT CustID,
       Count(*)
FROM TableName
WHERE 40 IN (SELECT *
             FROM Split(Code,','))
GROUP BY CustID
```